# Why does Medium's API prepend while(1) to the JSONP response?

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, get

just curious about https://medium.com I see that on their [search](https://medium.com/search) page they make an automatic `ajax GET`request, I opened up my firebug(cause of curiosity) and get results as follows:

(I typed the search phrase `sen` to trigger `GET` request to https://medium.com/search/all?q=sen. Note if you opened it, it won't work since it only expects ajax request)

`])}while(1);</x>{"success":true,"payload":{"value":{"posts":[{"id":"748b78360917","versionId":"9fbac25a3c7c","creatorId":"29fed3d34b82","homeCollectionId":"e196dfdf4b5d","title":"Nous sommes des clients, pas des usagers. Et ça change tout" // MORE JSON RESPONSE FROM SERVER....`

now the question is not about the `JSON` part, I want to know what does `])}while(1);</x>` mean in the response? What's the purpose of this?

**Updated**
I know that `while(1)` is for infinite loop, but why doing this?

**Update**
I read the similar question, now I know the use of 'while(1)' is to prevent json hijacking, but the '
])}while(1);' part is still confusing, why use '])}' and ''
? Isn't 'while(1)' enough?

Comment: There's no need to ask forgiveness for your curiousity; no one is punishing you for being curious.